# What are the arguments for censorship?

Tags: ethics

If one were to go by the Universal Declaration of Human Rights, everyone would have a "right" to "freedom of speech and expression"

The freedom calls for evaluative neutrality on part of the government, as offensive and discriminatory as the speech and expression may be

People believe censorship to be "ineffectual" or worse, drawing attention to and making martyrs out of censored populations, spreading rather than extinguishing fires, and weakening characters that would have matured and risen above difficulty

"What happened to stick and stones may break my bones, but words will never break me? Noone should be the arbiter of morality. *You* should learn to toughen up," they say

What does philosophy have to say about that?

Comment: I would recommend https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/freedom-speech/. The first thing to note is that "freedom of speech" is just another right that will clash with and will need to be balanced with other rights. That's IMHO a good start for this discussion.

Comment: One general concern is that unrestricted speech may become destructive to society or its vulnerable members, bans on "hate speech" and "corruption of the youth" are often so justified. Another concern is that too much of any freedom may give too much leeway to its enemies. This is Rosenfeld's version of Popper's [paradox of tolerance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradox_of_tolerance#Tolerance_and_freedom_of_speech);"*it seems contradictory to extend freedom of speech to extremists who ... if successful, ruthlessly suppress the speech of those with whom they disagree.*"

Comment: A moments thought shows that rights aren't unconditional. They must be balanced with other rights. For rights aren't singular but plural. This is a large part of what makes for ethics, law, philosophy and politics. Thus the right to speech, tgat is free speech, is not unconditional. It's an not an interesting question why some free speech advocates believe such a right supersedes all other values. Usually its because they haven't thought through their position. It's against the norms that such a balancing creates that censorship should be evaluated and not the norms itself which are establishe

Comment: One thing I will add for having worked in that domain at a social media platform recently, is that the issue of online censorship in particular is full of details and difficulties. For example, some users may try to abuse one platform by just using it to reach their audience with links to another platform where speech is controlled differently. What should the first platform do about those redirections?

Comment: As usual *time* is critical to the issue. This is the reason why *skepticism* is so very important.

Answer (score 1):

In the first place, censorship and information control is the norm in any functioning society. Our own First Amendment protections are a kind of negative "right" to express whatever makes no real difference in the structure and operations of social systems.

The most extensive restrictions on symbolic expression are simply normalized out of view. These include copyright restrictions, laws against counterfeiting, art forgeries, state secrets (such as nuclear weapons codes) patented information (including pharmaceuticals and software), and identity theft.

All these can be readily defined as forms of "speech" or information. Yet they are extensively restricted for quite obvious reasons, and such restrictions are expanding rapidly. There are several reasons for this.

First, modern philosophy has made clear how much of human consciousness and social organization can and must be defined in terms of "language." Language is irreducible, many would argue. Second, technology is more and more defined by and valued by the "information" it contains. Even something like a modern automobile is largely an amalgamation of information processors, accounting for much of its value and functionality. Finance is a form of social power that moves almost entirely in the abstract realm of digital information. Again, this has more than just a metaphorical relation to conversational "speech."

Finally, the above coupled with the fact that more and more of such objects and social processes are commodities, means that these information-bearing entities are extensively and increasingly restricted by property laws, a restriction on the use of information and "speech." Indeed, one can even be held liable for using certain common words and names, (even one's own family name, in some famous cases)
if it is trademarked.

This does not exactly answer your question, what are philosophical justifications for censorship. But I hope it establishes some context. It is more meaningful to ask what philosophical anarchist positions could justify a complete absence of "censorship." And in what contexts is information or individual "free speech" so functionally negligible that it requires no restriction?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that "free speech" vs "censorship" is some black and white shadow debate that isn't really meaningfully happening.

The thing is as soon as you have a society of 2 your "free speech" is limited. Because if you scream all the time the other person is "censored" and can't express themselves over your noise level and vice versa.
Meaning either a) both of your rights to free speech are meaningless as you theoretically possess them but practically can't make use of them or b) you have to limit "free speech" in it's scope so it's less than absolute, but in it's relativity at least receives some meaningful practical purpose.

Now people live life differently and make different experiences and it's generally helpful if people posses the ability to share their experiences, woes, joys, ideas and concepts. It's also often the least harmful form of communication. Unlike for example violence which is also a form of communication but a rather destructive one.

So there is some utility in having "free speech and free expression". The problem is "sticks and stones" is, has been and continues to be bullshit. Like words do harm and they often hit harder than punches. Also speech isn't just neutral speech is an action, like you can craft speech that is imperative, that establishes facts and that has a real influence.

Like the famous "FIRE!!!" in a crowded area is not just speech, it's establishing a fact that commands immediate action or harm incurs. And similarly you can craft all kinds of insidious narratives that undermine a pluralist society and demand prompt, direct and often violent action. And if that becomes the predominant form of communication your idea of "free speech" is again dead.

And it's not even that you can craft an easy list of "what not to say". Because anything has it's place to be said and it has a place and time where it better not be said because of harmful consequences.

Like even if you were in favor of one particular narrative and want to suppress all opposition, you might still rely on dissent at least to some degree otherwise no one will tell you that what you're doing doesn't work, which can have catastrophic results. As annoying as Nay-Sayers are, you don't want to be surrounded by Yay-Sayers either.

So this isn't really a debate about "pro free speech" or "pro censorship". But about where to draw the line to have a meaningful peaceful exchange without conflict that breaks the system and without violating other people and denying information about reality and different people tend to place that line differently. Usually "free speech for me but not for thee".